# Executing a script from Fiddler Autoresponder

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to test out a script locally using Fiddler Autoresponder rules and I have an endpoint that includes a hash of the request body in the response.  I figured I could just trigger a script from the autoresponder and calculate the hash and construct the response but it's been incredibly difficult to figure out how to do so.

As far as I can tell, scripts are supported by the AutoResponder but there's little to no documentation on it.  The only reference I can find is this post in the Fiddler forums (https://www.telerik.com/forums/script-in-autoresponder) but I have no idea where in the documentation that detail comes from.

I can get scripts to run, but it seems to run before the request is sent and I can't figure out how to have it execute the request as normal (or load the response from a file, or populate the response body from the script) and then execute my code to add the hash as a header.

I've messed around with the Session object a bit but can't find anything obvious.  Is there any better documentation for Fiddler that's actually up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a function that constructs a response which incorporates dynamic information from the request.

```
public static function UrbanDictionaryBlocker(oS: Session)
{   
    if (oS.HTTPMethodIs("GET")) // avoid HTTPS errors
    {
        oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        oS.ResponseBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("stop browsing urban dictionary at work: " + oS.fullUrl);
    }
}
```

I wrote an associated rule which maps URLs containing "urbandictionary" to this function.

**How I figured this out:**

I figured this out by setting up [Fiddler extension develoment in Visual Studio](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/ExtendWithDotNet), which gives much better intellisense for the Fiddler API. Using *go to definition*, I was then able to conveniently view a list of all methods on the Session class.

Example:

```
...
        [CodeDescription("Returns true if request URI contains the specified string. Case-insensitive.")]
        public bool uriContains(string sLookfor);
        [CodeDescription("Copy an existing Session's response to this Session, bypassing the server if not already contacted")]
        public void utilAssignResponse(Session oFromSession);
        [CodeDescription("Copy an existing response to this Session, bypassing the server if not already contacted")]
        public void utilAssignResponse(HTTPResponseHeaders oRH, byte[] arrBody);
        [CodeDescription("Use BZIP2 to compress the response body. Throws exceptions to caller.")]
        public bool utilBZIP2Response();
        [CodeDescription("Apply Transfer-Encoding: chunked to the response, if possible.")]
        public bool utilChunkResponse(int iSuggestedChunkCount);
        [CodeDescription("Call inside OnBeforeRequest to create a Response object and bypass the server.")]
        public void utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        [CodeDescription("Removes chunking and HTTP Compression from the Request. Adds or updates Content-Length header.")]
        public bool utilDecodeRequest();
        public bool utilDecodeRequest(bool bSilent);
        [CodeDescription("Removes chunking and HTTP Compression from the response. Adds or updates Content-Length header.")]
        public bool utilDecodeResponse();
...
```

And then I guessed that `utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer` was the tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks!  I also figured out that you can use `oS.LoadResponseFromStream(new MemoryStream(), null);` as an easy way to sidestep the request process.  From there you can set the status code and various other properties as necessary.

I like suggestion to use Visual Studio for better intellisense, I'll try that out next time.